# Walking backwards from the kotel - minhag or din?

Tags: halacha, kotel-western-wall

Minhag or din?
Apart from this [Magen Avraham on not turning your back on the heichel](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=419) (which I don't know if it is a din or minhag), could anyone point me to support for the practice of walking backwards away from the kotel? 
If it is a din, how do you determine at which point do you turn back to your normal walking direction?
It is not a duplicate of question as the kotel may or may not be treated halachically differently.

Comment: @DonielF it's certainly a shul.  Perhaps if the question was reworded to ask if such a minhag or din exists for the kosel even if it wouldn't be a shul?

Comment: @don Not a duplicate since that question doesn't ask at which point one turns around, which may be unique at the kotel which doesn't have doorways.

Comment: I like that a Yerushalmi would ask about the Kotel :-) @רבותמחשבות mentions a good point that we currently treat it as a "shul", so in that sense, it should have the same rules. However, I wonder if the Kotel has a higher or different status than a normal shul as it is a remnant of the Bet Hamikdash? Or does it have no Kedusha as such? For clarity, is your question based on this assumption? If so, you may want to edit in this point.

Comment: @danf the kotel is not a remenant of the beit hamikdash

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks. In other words, all these years, we've just been talking to a wall?

Comment: @danf we've been talking to God at a wall

Comment: @DonielF Not a dup because I assumed kotel may be treated as holier than a regular shul, as DanF explained. If the halachic treatment is the same, this question nevertheless stands because it is a reasonable question to ask in light of the difference in holiness.

Comment: Moreover, that answer to the question about shuls does not state whether it is a minhag or din - that is the question i would like to ask.

Comment: This might be a better and more direct link https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.132.6

Comment: @hazoriz thank you :) definitely appreciate a helpful comment!

Comment: @Yerushalmi you are welcome , I am happy to help a Jew, (BTW there also is http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x507 )

Comment: @hazoriz, on top of ahavas yisroel you did ahavas hager. it's buy one get one free by me. I'm quite a beginner at lashon hakodesh, is it the best way to arrive at a source by typing a hebrew keyword in Sefaria? (second to remembering the actual source, of course)

Comment: @Yerushalmi thank you for the opportunity. I do not know what is the best way, what I did was click on the saif in the shulchan aruch https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.132.2 then clicked on commentary https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.132.2?with=Commentary then on Mogain Avraham